# json schema not allow multiple same nodes

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

In my application i have to test that the json that gets sent back to us validates an exact format - in my case, that there is a Body and a Head Block, but not more. I validated the given json schema against the 2 JSONs and both are valid - is there a way to not let multiple "Head" or "Body" nodes pass?

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "ValidResponse",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Head": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "Body": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required":["Head", "Body"]
}
```

This Block should validate Wrong! ---v

```
{
   "Body" : {
   },
   "Head" : {
   },
   "Head" : {
   }
}
```

This Block should validate right! ---v

```
{
   "Body" : {
   },
   "Head" : {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your input is not valid JSON, so you should use a JSON parser or linter that errors on such input before passing it to a schema checker.

Most JSON parsers will silently ignore one of the duplicate `Head` properties though. In any case, your JSON Schema checker will never know that there was input containing duplicate properties.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to let the json schema check wether the json is a right json-format or not ... the Json Format itself has to be right before checking the schema

Comment: Yes you have to validate the JSON itself, when it's still text with a linter or with a JSON parser that does this sort of validation (no idea if there is any).

Answer (score 0):

This block is not valid...

```
{
   "Body" : {
   },
   "Head" : {
   },
   "Head" : {
   }
}
```

You can run it through a validator such as http://jsonlint.com/

If whatever validator you're using says it's valid it's a problem with the validator.

Comment: http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ ... thought this validator works as it seems rather "official"